# How to draw graphics in a child window?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am adding some graphics to the map in a parent window, and I would like to show the same graphics in a child window. I am using the ArcGIS Javascript API (version 3.1). I have written code as below:

Complete code in parent window:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ePermit.Test.Test1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples  
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>GIS Search </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.1/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <%--<link href="Styles/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
        }
        #header
        {
            height: 30px;
            padding: 15px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #d0eff3;
            color: #80a8c1;
            font-size: 21pt;
            text-align: left;
            border: solid 2px #80a8c1;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #leftPane
        {
            float: left;
            padding-right:8px;
            margin:0px;
            background-color: #fafafa;
            color: #80a8c1;
            border: solid 1px #80a8c1;
        }

        #rightPane
        {
            float: right;            
            background-color: #fafafa;
            color: #80a8c1;
            border: solid 1px #80a8c1;
            width:22%;

        }
        #centerPane
        {
            float: left;
            margin: 0px auto;
            padding: 0px 10px;
            background-color:#CCCCCC;
        }
        #results
        {
            background-color: #00FFFF;
            color: #80a8c1;
            text-align: center;
            border: solid 0px #80a8c1;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px 10px;
         }

        .roundedCorners
        {
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -o-border-radius: 4px;
        }

        /*Example of a id selector, using the # side with an element name will 
      apply this style to a single unique element, in this case the html element 
      with an id of 'map'.*/
        #map
        {
            margin: 5px;
            border: solid 1px #80a8c1;
        }
        .dijitBorderContainer, .dijitGutter
        {
            background-color: #d0eff3 !important;
        }
        /*Example of a class selector, using a period in front of an HTML elment 
      allows you to specify a style for multiple elements. All elements with 
      a class attribute set to the specified value will have this style applied.*/
        .shadow
        {
            padding: 8px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px #888;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px #888;
            box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px #888;
            background-color: white;
            border: solid 4px #80a8c1;
        }
        .mapOverviewIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/toggleov.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .zoomToFullIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/fullextent.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .zoomToActiveIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/zoomactive.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .zoomToBackIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/back2ex.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .zoominIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/zoomin16.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .zoomoutIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/zoomout16.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .pan
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/pan.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }

        .identityIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/identify.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .printIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/print.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .refreshIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/refresh.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .plssHistoryIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/history_icon.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .plssAcreageIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/acreage_icon.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .plssAccurayIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/accuracy_icon.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
        .clearLayersIcon
        {
            background-image: url(../images/Icons/reset_plsstool.GIF);
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }

        .xouter
        {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

        .floatstop {
            clear:both;
         } 

          .floatstopl {
            clear:left;
         } 

          .floatstopr {
            clear:right;
         } 

.esriOverviewMap.ovwTL .ovwShow, .esriOverviewMap.ovwBR .ovwHide {
    display: none !important;
}
.esriOverviewMap.ovwTR .ovwShow, .esriOverviewMap.ovwBL .ovwHide {
    display: none !important;
}
.esriOverviewMap.ovwBL .ovwShow, .esriOverviewMap.ovwTR .ovwHide {
    display: none !important;
}
.esriOverviewMap.ovwBR .ovwShow, .esriOverviewMap.ovwTL .ovwHide {
    display: none !important;
}
.esriOverviewMap .logo-med, .esriOverviewMap .logo-sm, .esriOverviewMap .bingLogo-lg {
    display: none !important;
}




    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var djConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: true
        }; 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="AddPoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.dijit");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.Toolbar");
        dojo.require("esri.toolbars.navigation");
        dojo.require("dijit.Tooltip");
        dojo.require("esri.map");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
        dojo.require("esri.arcgis.utils");
        dojo.require("esri.dijit.OverviewMap");


        var map, navToolbar, layer, visible = [];
        var m_glayer;
        function init() {

            var initExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({ "xmin": -111.23080504945419, "ymin": 40.28582425473493, "xmax": -103.87680757086906, "ymax": 45.71549561177383, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 4608} });
            map = new esri.Map("map", { logo: false, slider: false });


            layer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://myserver/WSIPL/rest/services/myservice/MapServer");
            //map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);

            navToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Navigation(map);


            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.setExtent(initExtent);

            //Add Map Overview
            dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', function (theMap) {
                overviewMapDijit = new esri.dijit.OverviewMap({
                    map: map,
                    extent: initExtent,
                    visible: true,
                    attachTo: "top-left"
                });
                overviewMapDijit.startup();
                ov = true;
            });

            m_glayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
            dojo.connect(layer, "onLoad", printPreview);


        }




        function printPreview() {
            dojo.connect(map, 'onClick', function () {
                var x = -110.893677;
                var y = 44.058510;
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    addPoint(x, y);
                    x = x + 0.001;
                    y = y + 0.001;
                }
            });
        }


        function addPoint(x, y) {
            var point = new esri.geometry.Point(x, y, map.spatialReference);
            var simpleMarkerSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
            var graphic = new esri.Graphic(point, simpleMarkerSymbol);

            m_glayer.add(graphic);

            map.addLayer(m_glayer);

        }




        function showPrintWindow() {
            var xMin = document.getElementById('hfxmin').value;
            var xMax = document.getElementById('hfxmax').value;
            var yMin = document.getElementById('hfymin').value;
            var yMax = document.getElementById('hfymax').value;

            printWin = window.open("../WebForm3.aspx?XMin=" + xMin + "&XMax=" + xMax + "&YMin=" + yMin + "&YMax=" + yMax, null, "status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes");
        }

        dojo.addOnLoad(init);

    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="mainWindow" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="false"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div id="leftPane" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="left" style="width: 3%;">
            <div id="navToolbar" dojotype="dijit.Toolbar" class="dojotool">


                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="mapOverview" title="Toggles Vicinity Map" iconclass="mapOverviewIcon"
                    onclick="ShowHideOVMap()" align="center">
                </div>


                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="zoomToFull" title="Zoom to Full Extent" align="center"
                    iconclass="zoomToFullIcon" onclick="navToolbar.zoomToFullExtent();">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="zoomToActive" title="Zoom to Active Layer"
                    align="center" iconclass="zoomToActiveIcon" onclick="normalTool();changeDojoHighlight(this.id);navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.ZOOM_IN);map.enableScrollWheelZoom();">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="zoomToBack" title="Zoom to Previous Extent"
                    align="center" iconclass="zoomToBackIcon" onclick="navToolbar.zoomToPrevExtent();">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="zoomin" title="Zoom In" iconclass="zoominIcon"
                    align="center" onclick="navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.ZOOM_IN);">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="zoomout" title="Zoom Out" iconclass="zoomoutIcon"
                    align="center" onclick="navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="pan" title="Recenter" iconclass="pan" align="center"
                    onclick="navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.PAN);">
                </div>

                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="identity" title="Identify Features" iconclass="identityIcon"
                    align="center" onclick="">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="print" title="Print" iconclass="printIcon"
                    align="center" onclick="showPrintWindow()">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="refresh" title="Refresh" iconclass="refreshIcon"
                    align="center" onclick="">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="plssHistory" title="History"
                    iconclass="plssHistoryIcon" align="center" onclick="">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="plssAcreage" title="Acreage" iconclass="plssAcreageIcon"
                    align="center" onclick="">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="plssAccuracy" title="Accuracy" iconclass="plssAccurayIcon"
                    align="center" onclick="">
                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.form.Button" id="clearLayers" title="Clear Layer" iconclass="clearLayersIcon"
                    align="center" onclick="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="floatstopl>&nbsp;</div>






          <div id="rightPane" class="roundedCorners" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="right"
            style="width: 22%;">
            <div dojotype="dijit.layout.TabContainer">
                <div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="QUERIES" selected="true">

                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="TOC">
                    Content for the second tab
                     Layer List : <span id="layer_list"></span><br /> 

                </div>
                <div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="LEGEND">
                    Content for the third tab
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>         



        <div id="centerpane" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" region="center" gutters="false">
            <%--<div id="map" dojotype="dijit.layout.contentpane" class="shadow" region="center"
                style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
            </div>--%>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           <%-- <button onclick="map.panUpperLeft();"></button>--%>
                           <img src="images/Icons/north_l.gif" alt="northwest" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <%--<button onclick="map.panUp();"></button>--%>
                            <img src="images/Icons/n_arrow.gif" alt="north"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%--<button onclick="map.panUpperRight();"> </button>--%>
                            <img src="images/Icons/north_r.gif"  alt="northeast"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <%--<button onclick="map.panLeft();"></button>--%>
                            <img src="images/Icons/w_arrow.gif" alt="west"/>   
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="map" style="width: 610px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid #000;">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <%--<button onclick="map.panRight();"></button>--%>
                            <img src="images/Icons/e_arrow.gif" alt="east"/>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%--<button onclick="map.panLowerLeft();"> </button>--%>
                            <img src="images/Icons/south_l.gif" alt="southwest" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <%--<button onclick="map.panDown();"></button>--%>
                            <img src="images/Icons/s_arrow.gif" alt="south"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%--<button onclick="map.panLowerRight();"></button>--%>
                            <img src="images/Icons/south_r.gif" alt="southeast"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="floatstopl"></div>
    <div id="results" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="bottom" style="width:700px; height:100px;" >
            This is the results section
        </div>

     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfxmin" runat="server" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfxmax" runat="server" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfymin" runat="server" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfymax" runat="server" />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Complete code in Child window:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="ePermit.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples    on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>GIS Search </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.1/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <%--<link href="Styles/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var djConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: true
        }; 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.1"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="AddPoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       dojo.require("esri.map");
       var map;

       function init() {
           //var initialExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({ "xmin": -400, "ymin": -400, "xmax": 400, "ymax": 400, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 102100} });
           var fltxmin = parseFloat(document.getElementById('<%=hfxmin.ClientID%>').value);
           var fltxmax = parseFloat(document.getElementById('<%=hfxmax.ClientID%>').value);
           var fltymin = parseFloat(document.getElementById('<%=hfymin.ClientID%>').value);
           var fltymax = parseFloat(document.getElementById('<%=hfymax.ClientID%>').value);

           var initialExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({ "xmin": fltxmin, "ymin": fltymin, "xmax": fltxmax, "ymax": fltymax, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 4269} });
           //var initExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({ "xmin": -111.40, "ymin": 44.31, "xmax": -110.10, "ymax": 45.17, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 4608} });
           map = new esri.Map("map", {logo: true, slider: true});


           dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", function (map) { map.infoWindow.resize(100, 100); });

           var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(http://myserver/WSIPL/rest/services/myservice/MapServer);

           map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);
           map.setExtent(initialExtent);



           map.addLayer(m_glayer);

//           dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", map, "disablePan");
//           dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", map, "disableMapNavigation");
//           dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", map, "disableScrollWheelZoom");          
//           dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", map, "disableKeyboardNavigation()");
       }

       dojo.addOnLoad(init);

    </script>
</head>

 <body class="claro">
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="map" style="width:600px; height:400px; border:1px solid #000;"></div>
    <div id="info" style="padding:5px; margin:5px; background-color:#eee;"></div>  
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfxmin" runat="server" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfxmax" runat="server" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfymin" runat="server" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfymax" runat="server" />
     </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

When user click on print button child widow should open with the same graphics as in parent window.

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: Please put your code to {code} tag

Comment: I think in child window it will not display..

Comment: You can use Ctrl-K to auto-indent code blocks by 4 spaces, which will format it correctly.

Comment: @user14628 Can you post the complete code from both windows? I have done something similar by displaying a new page with a callback function that has access to both the pages. How exactly are you doing it?

Comment: Hi Devdatta, I have edited my question with complete code in parent window and child window. please let me know if you require anything more.

Answer (score 3):

I would request you to look at this answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/901278/895

Here is how I transferred some Information from one window to a child window.

In My main Window, I have the following JavaScript:

```
var helper = { // pseudo namespace

map: null,

/*-- print --*/

print_window: null,

openPrintWindow: function() {
  helper.print_window = window.open('print.html', '<Title>', 'width=1100,height=700,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0,menubar=1,location=0,personalbar=0,navigation=0,resizable=0');
},

// called by child window after it has finished loading
printWindowReadyCallback: function() {

  helper.print_window.applyMapSettings(helper.map); //or you can pass something else as well

}    
};
```

In the child window, I have the body onload listener setup like this:

```
<body onLoad="init()" >
```

My JavaScript in the child window is something like this:

```
function init() {
      opener.helper.printWindowReadyCallback();
    }

    function applyMapSettings(source_map) {
    //do whatever you need to here.

}

}
```

Whenever I need to open the new Window & pass the variables, I do this:

```
this.helper.map=this.map;
this.helper.openPrintWindow();
```